# setState not .slicing() into state's array the way I'm intending

Tags: reactjs, setstate

**Background:**

I'm developing an itinerary builder which is made up of rows, or component instances named EventContainers, that represent an activity on a user's given day.

The class, shown below, has an array in state.events that accepts EventContainers from the setState in the pushNewEventContainerToState function.

Of note, each EventContainer contains a button that is intended to give the user the ability to onClick an additional row/EventContainer by calling pushNewEventContainerToState.

The same button is also listed as its own component instance, named NewEventButton, and is displayed before any EventContainers.

Any EventContainer that is setStated to state.events is supposed to be placed in the index immediately after the EventContainer that calls setState, not at the beginning or end.

**Method**

I'm using .slice() in setState with the intention of doing just that => placing the newest EventContainer in the index immediately following the EventContainer that called setstate.

**Problem**

However, there are three issues I see:

a) Only the very first button, NewEventButton, will actually call setState. The buttons on the new EventContainer's won't do anything.

b) The EventContainers that pass through setState seem to be .pushed() to state.events, not .sliced(), but I don't need them at the end of the array.

c) When I check on Chrome devtools, I see that any EventContainer that's setStated to state.events is undefined.

**What I've tried**

I've tried placing two different kinds of props directly into the EventContainer that's inside pushNewEventContainerToState:

```
1. The first prop I tried didn't do anything -> onClick={() => this.pushNewEventContainerToState(index)

2. The second prop I tried was the same as the first except, instead of onClick, I named it pushNewEventContainerToState. This got the button on new EventContainers working but the EventContainers seemed to again be .pushed() instead of .sliced the way I need them to be. Chrome devtools will then show this is defined but I don't see a bound like I do for the first NewEventButton.
```

Thank you very much for taking a look.

```
class DayContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      events: [],

    };

    this.pushNewEventContainerToState = this.pushNewEventContainerToState.bind(this);
  }



      pushNewEventContainerToState(index) {
        let newEvent = < EventContainer / > ;

        this.setState(prevState => {
          const updatedEvents = [...prevState.events.slice(0, index), newEvent, ...prevState.events.slice(index + 1)];

            return {
              events: updatedEvents
            };
        })
      }

  render(){
    return (
        <>
          <div>
              <ul>

                  {
                    this.state.events === null
                    ? <EventContainer pushNewEventContainerToState={this.pushNewEventContainerToState} />
                    : <NewEventButton pushNewEventContainerToState={this.pushNewEventContainerToState} />
                  }


                  {this.state.events.map((item, index) => (
                    <li
                        key={item}
                        onClick={() => this.pushNewEventContainerToState(index)}
                    >{item}</li>
                  ))}

              </ul>

          </div>
        </>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use a 2 dimensional array?

Comment: Can you put this into a reproducible demo using Codesandbox or something?

Comment: Thank you, will take a look these as soon as I address kbo's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try fixing this part of your function first, looks like it doesn't behave as expected:

```
[...prevState.events.slice(0, index), newEvent, ...prevState.events.slice(index + 1)]
```

change to:

```
[...prevState.events.slice(0, index), newEvent, ...prevState.events.slice(index)]
```

.slice()'s second argument tells it to stop there, but doesn't include the index of the element. So if you have [1, 2, 3].slice(0,1) in example, you'll get only the first element -> [1]. 
Hope that fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks @kbo, I'm still having issues with EventContainer being .pushed but I'm on a better track now. Will take a closer look at the slice issue.